# Причина закрытия окна Windows Forms

Tags: c#, winforms, события, формы

Всем привет. Я хочу узнать причину закрытия следующего окна.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Дело в том, что `CloseReason.UserClosing` ставится в `true` как при закрытии на крестик, так и при нажатии на кнопку "Принять". А мне нужно узнать был ли нажат конкретно крестик. Как это можно реализовать?

Код обработки кнопки:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            fileName = textBox1.Text;
            this.Close();
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Простой пример с DialogResult

```
public class MyForm : Form
{
    public MyForm()
    {
        var bt = new Button() {Text = "Apply"};
        this.Controls.Add(bt);
        bt.Click += (sender, args) =>
        {           
            this.DialogResult = DialogResult.Yes; // также тут можно вернуть OK, Abort, и так далее
            this.Close();           
        };
    }
}
```

как проверить

```
var form = new MyForm();
var ret = form.ShowDialog();
Console.WriteLine(ret);
```

При нажатии на крестик вернет Cancel, при нажатии на кнопку - Yes